# Vue electron builder - needed assets not included into the portable win app

Tags: windows, vue.js, ms-access, electron, electron-builder

I'm using vue cli electron builder latest version that is in alpha to create a custom application that is vue 3 powered. After some trouble due to the main field that is not needed anymore needed from the latest version of electron. At the mement I need to build a portable standalone app that needs to include some MS Access mdb files but I'm unable to obtain the desired result, tha app will also fail to load bootstrap icons.

This is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "riftool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --win portable",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve ",
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@el3um4s/node-adodb": "^5.0.17",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "docx-preview": "^0.1.15",
    "easy-template-x": "^3.1.0",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron/rebuild": "^3.2.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "electron": "24.3.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^3.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

and this is my vue.config,js file

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            preload: 'src/preload.js',
            mainProcessWatch: ['./public/index.html'],
            outputDir: 'dist/rtool',
            appId: 'rtool.cs.com',
            files: [ '**/*' ]
        }
    },
    productionSourceMap: false
})
```

I'm importing directly the icons into the main entry point file of the vue app and in serve mode all is working fine. What I've noticed that into the destination folder I've indicated, I will have an exe and an unpacked version of the app. Any help or suggestion please?